# ChunkLoadError: cannot load js asset in jekyll site on AWS S3/CloudFront

Tags: javascript, ruby, amazon-s3, jekyll, amazon-cloudfront

**TL;DR** The browser is able to download a js asset, but the main js is not able to "load" it.

*NOTE:* I have no experience with javascript or web development.

## The problem

I'm using the [Hydejack](https://hydejack.com/) Jekyll theme to build a website. The main javascript is not able to load some other js assets, even though the browser is able to download the js asset. See the full error message below.

Basically, this script:

- https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js

Is trying to load these scripts:

- [https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/vendors~push-state-hydejack-9.1.6.js](https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/vendors%7Epush-state-hydejack-9.1.6.js)
- https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/drawer-hydejack-9.1.6.js

The function that tries to load the js asset throws a `ChunkLoadError` error. Now, the trouble is that the function is completely unreadable and is therefore difficult to debug.

The website can be found here: https://www.olavur.consulting/

### Error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 13 failed.
(missing: https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/vendors~drawer-hydejack-9.1.6.js)
    e https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:28
    o https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
[hydejack-9.1.6.js:13:1115](https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js)
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 16 failed.
(missing: https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/vendors~push-state-hydejack-9.1.6.js)
    e https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:28
    o https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
    <anonymous> https://www.olavur.consulting/assets/js/hydejack-9.1.6.js:13
```

## The website

The website is build with jekyll v4.3.3 and ruby 3.3.0.

```
gem install webrick jekyll bundle
bundle install
JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build
```

It is hosted on an AWS S3 bucket and delivered via an AWS CloudFront distribution.

## Debugging

If i *serve* the site locally, as follows, the site works perfectly, when browsing it on `localhost:4000`.

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll serve
```

That is, the problem only arises when I `build` the site and browse the site via the S3/CloudFront setup.

I've tried playing around with the CSP settings of the site. But since the HTTP GET request to the js asset succeeds, I have to assume this is not the problem.

I've also tried making the CORS settings more lenient, but that didn't help either.

I've also tried completely rebuilding the site, invalidating the files on the CloudFront distribution, and disabling caching for my site in the browser. No dice.